# Numba list argument for array indexing

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm looking to leverage numba to iterate over a large 2d array, where for iteration a subset of the array will be selected by [x, y] location (passed as an argument). I'm having trouble with structuring this the right way to play nice with numba, specifically when passing a list of lists as an argument into the method. Any pointers?

```
x_y_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
array = ([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

@jit
def arrIndexing(array, x_y_list):
    for index in x_y_list:
        subset = array[index[0]-1:index[0]+1, index[1]-1:index[1]+1]
        # do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? 
Should do well with Numba but I haven’t tested (did this on my phone which doesn’t support Numba)

```
import numpy as np

def xy():
    x_y_list = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 4], [0, 5]])
    array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
    for i,j in x_y_list:
        print(array[np.ix_((i-1, i), (j-1, j))])


>>> xy()
[[2 3]
 [2 3]]
[[4 5]
 [4 5]]
[[5 6]
 [5 6]]
```